# JNI error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a native method that displays the file owner for a given path.

```
public class ACL{
    static {
      System.loadLibrary("owner"); // hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
   }
    // Declare native method
    private native String displayFileOwner(String path);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String str = "C:/Users/pradeep-pt3689/eclipse-workspace/Permission/jni/owner.c";
      System.out.println(":"+new ACL().displayFileOwner(str));
    }
}
```

The code showing this error on running

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ACL.displayFileOwner(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
> at ACL.displayFileOwner(Native Method)
> at ACL.main(ACL.java:10)

The native code is:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "ACL.h"
#include "accctrl.h"
#include "aclapi.h"

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_ACL_displayFileOwner(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring path)
{
jstring jstr=NULL;
const char *str=env->GetStringUTFChars(path, NULL);
DWORD dwRtnCode = 0;
PSID pSidOwner = NULL;
BOOL bRtnBool = TRUE;
LPTSTR AcctName = NULL;
LPTSTR DomainName = NULL;
DWORD dwAcctName = 1, dwDomainName = 1;
SID_NAME_USE eUse = SidTypeUnknown;
HANDLE hFile;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;

// Get the handle of the file object.
hFile = CreateFile(
                  str,
                  GENERIC_READ,
                  FILE_SHARE_READ,
                  NULL,
                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                  NULL);

// Check GetLastError for CreateFile error code.
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          jstr = env->NewStringUTF("CreateFile error.\n");
          return jstr;
}

// Get the owner SID of the file.
dwRtnCode = GetSecurityInfo(
                  hFile,
                  SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                  OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                  &pSidOwner,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  &pSD);

// Check GetLastError for GetSecurityInfo error condition.
if (dwRtnCode != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          jstr = env->NewStringUTF("GetSecurityInfo error.\n");
          return jstr;
}

// First call to LookupAccountSid to get the buffer sizes.
bRtnBool = LookupAccountSid(
                  NULL,           // local computer
                  pSidOwner,
                  AcctName,
                  (LPDWORD)&dwAcctName,
                  DomainName,
                  (LPDWORD)&dwDomainName,
                  &eUse);

// Reallocate memory for the buffers.
AcctName = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(
          GMEM_FIXED,
          dwAcctName);

// Check GetLastError for GlobalAlloc error condition.
if (AcctName == NULL) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          jstr = env->NewStringUTF("GlobalAlloc error.\n");
          return jstr;
}

    DomainName = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(
           GMEM_FIXED,
           dwDomainName);

    // Check GetLastError for GlobalAlloc error condition.
    if (DomainName == NULL) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          jstr = env->NewStringUTF("GlobalAlloc error.\n");
          return jstr;

    }

    // Second call to LookupAccountSid to get the account name.
    bRtnBool = LookupAccountSid(
          NULL,                   // name of local or remote computer
          pSidOwner,              // security identifier
          AcctName,               // account name buffer
          (LPDWORD)&dwAcctName,   // size of account name buffer
          DomainName,             // domain name
          (LPDWORD)&dwDomainName, // size of domain name buffer
          &eUse);                 // SID type

    // Check GetLastError for LookupAccountSid error condition.
    if (bRtnBool == FALSE) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();

          if (dwErrorCode == ERROR_NONE_MAPPED)
              jstr = env->NewStringUTF("Account owner not found for specified SID.\n");
          else
                jstr = env->NewStringUTF("Error in LookupAccountSid.\n");
          return jstr;

    } else if (bRtnBool == TRUE)

        {// Print the account name.
        jstr = env->NewStringUTF(AcctName);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path, str);
    }
    return jstr;
}
```

The same jni methods I actually used in the web project to get the file path in textfield and print owner which works perfectly fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12lo1.jpg)

Comment: Check the exported symbols of your dll with dumpbin. Edit your question to show us all symbols that contain displayFileProperty

Comment: Ok, this sounds weird but I try compiling the same type of method with string return type it worked perfectly fine under the different project name. I even tried copying that only simple code snippet into the above C source file and it stills throws same error. I still didn't understand what is the issue.

Comment: Java is complaining about missing symbols, so check the symbols with dumpbin. That will tell you what is going on.

Comment: Did you put your class in a different package? Add the corresponding C code to your question and the dumpbin/nm output as Botje said and include the package name in your Java code.

Comment: I tried running the same code on a different machine and it works but here it says can't load the dll file. How to check with the dump bin? I never used or heard. @Botje

Comment: Provide the output of `dumpbin /symbols ownerInfo.dll`

Comment: I think dumpbin is VS tool. Since I'm not using VS, can you tell some other way aound. @Botje

Comment: The error message in your question does *not* mean "can't load the dll file". If you get a different error message now, please edit your question accordingly. And please provide all the code (minimal reproducible example)

Comment: Do you have `strings`? Is there a string with following value in the DLL: `Java_ownerInfo_displayFileProperty`? (Maybe with the package between `Java_` and `ownerInfo`)

Comment: Yes there's file defining string in the native method. As I said earlier the code worked fine in the different machine but not anymore in this. @JCWasmx86

Comment: Maybe on the other machine, where it doesn't work, there is an older version?

Comment: I had java 9 on the previous machine where it works. Here I have java 1.8 and java 9 as well. but I'm using java 1.8. How should I compile using java 9?

Comment: If you're using mingw you can use `nm` to dump the symbols of your dll. Possibly with a flag. Check the documentation.

Comment: I have edited the question.Please have a look. @Botje

Comment: That is c++ code, not c! You're missing the `extern "C" ` tag to make the symbol visible with the correct name. This is why I was asking for the dumpbin/nm output from the start. You wouldn't happen to have a header with such a declaration for `Java_ACL_displayFileOwner` that you forgot to include, would you?

Comment: If you are talking about the header file, it does have extern "C" code. @Botje

Comment: Did you also include it? For the fourth time, please show us what symbols your dll exports.

Comment: Sorry, I just dont get t how to generate this symbols you are talking about. I'm not using VS. How should I generate it? @Botje

Comment: I have used this dll export function. It gave me output like this. Function name=Java_ACL_displayFileOwner , Ordinal=1 (0x1) , Relative address=0x00001430 , Address=0x6c741430 , Type=Exported Function @Botje

Comment: @Margie Try Dependency Walker if you don't have the Visual Studio tools: https://www.dependencywalker.com/ This was part of old Visual Studio but is distributed separately now.

Comment: The following may not apply to Windows, but for the JVM on Linux, libraries that the native library depends on need to be loaded prior to calling `LoadLibrary` on the native lib.

Comment: Ok, I had different sample HelloWorld project taking a string as a parameter and return type string native method, which god knows working. I just copied the getOwner code in that and made the required changes it worked. @TainToTain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who's still facing this issue. Please try a simple JNI HelloWorld program execution and see if it works. In my case, a program passing string and returning name work perfectly fine, while the same method type passing file path and returning owner doesn't work.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_TestJNIString_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jstring inJNIStr) {
  
   const char *inCStr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, inJNIStr, NULL);
   return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, inCStr);
}
```

Now try to add different simple methods if you have, with above one in the same JNI code, and see it works. I had a complex method returning the ACL of a file with a return type string array. I tried executing a different method returning days of the week as string array and it works.

Now after executing the above JNI methods, make changes to the logic of your method but not return type and arguments passing.

It's weird but it worked.